# How to limit the number of rows in a sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Assume that we have a SharePoint list and we want to limit the maximum number of rows to 10 and whenever the user reaches that limit we should inform him / her with a notification in the UI. I'm using SharePoint 2010 and I know that it is possible to write an event receiver for the list but then it is not possible to access UI to show the notification and may be I should write a custom action for adding items and create a user control to collect details but then is it possible to remove add item link under the list view and is it realy the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot for sharing your ideas.

Comment: What business problem are you solving? Why do you need to enforce such limitation?

Comment: If you create an synchronous event receiver, the user will see that something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to edit the newitem form for that list in order to insert a custom server control that checks how many records that user has committed.

if number of records is equal to 10 then don't allow the submission. You can do this in several ways. One of them is to hide all the controls inside the dataformwebpart including the save button, except a panel with a message for the user.

Check here on how to insert custom controls in a DataFormWebPart:

http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/01/26/extending-the-dataform-web-part-to-allow-custom-field-controls.aspx

I would still complement it with an event handler throwing an exception just in case users can bypass your implementation (using client side code to prevent the submission comes to mind)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is given here: [kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePointListItemsLimit.htm](http://kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePointListItemsLimit.htm)

Basically, you first fill the list with the maximum number of items allowed, and then enforce a validation on items, for example do not allow their created date to be newer than the date you are doing this.